# Manage a database in an xml file

Tags: c#, xml, database, collections

I want to save some details in some kind of a DB.
I thought that using a DB like access or mysql would be an overkill.
Therefore, I've been planning to use a XML file as the DB.
My idea was to create an xml file in some kind of structure, such as:

```
<DB>
<Player>John</Player>
<Money>50</Money>
<Player>James</Player>
<Money>10</Money>
</DB>
```

Then, load this data into some kind of collection, manage it there and overwrite the xml file.

Is there any better way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I think that i'm being too complicated.

Edit:
I've added a method that serializes the data and saves it:

```
public static DB LoadFromFile(string path)
{
    FileStream fs = null;
    DB db = null;

    try
    {
        fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DB));
        db = (DB)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    if (fs != null)
    {
        fs.Close();
    }

    return db;
}

public static void SaveToFile(string path, object objData)
{
    var fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create);
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(objData.GetType());

    try
    {
        serializer.Serialize(fs, objData);
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    fs.Close();
}
```

When I'm trying to LoadFromFile after SaveToFile has been called I'm getting:
+       InnerException  {" Was Unexpected."}    System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: You might look into serialization. You can create classes, set properties on them, and then serialize them to xml and write them to a file. And vice versa...read a file, deserialize the xml into new classes, and you're ready to go. Check out: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/815813

Comment: Every time I've seen an application where the developer has said "a database will be overkill, I'll just use files" (or some other method), the developer has regretted it!

Comment: You could alternatively use `DataSet`. There are `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` functions that you can use to write and read from file. This may make it easier to migrate to database in the future. You can define primary keys and relationships. You can also handle row added, changed and deleted events. There are many other features available, without needing a database. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx but if none of the features are useful to you, might as well use `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use the XmlSerializer like so

```
public class User
{
    public string Player { get; set; }
    public string Money{ get; set; }
}
public class Database
{
    public List<User> User { get; set; }
    public static Database LoadFromFile(string path)
    {
        var fs = File.Open(path);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataBase));
        var db = (Database)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
        return db;
    }
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx for more information

Comment: I've added a method that serializes XML to the file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: error messsage, code etc.? update the question or create a new one